# How do I encrypt/decrypt a folder in a JavaScript web app without having to download all of it?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

Let's say I am developing a photo browser web app that supports local, client-side encryption and online backup. The file structure I would want to store (encrypted) could look like

```
/wedding
    /photo-1.jpg
    /photo-2.jpg
/selfies
    /me.png
```

One solution would be to archive the files together using `tar-js`, encrypt it with AES, and upload it to the server. However, if the folder gets too large, I would have to download, decrypt, and untar the entire thing in memory, which is obviously not desirable and could be impossible depending on how many photos the user uploads.

Is there a lightweight encryption scheme (with a JavaScript port) that includes a header in the encrypted file with the folder structure, so that I can download and decrypt files as I need them using HTTP Range Requests? There is an [online explanation](http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/01/truecrypt-explained.html) about how TrueCrypt accomplishes this, but I don't want to roll my own crypto.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't individually encrypt the files and folder names?

Comment: I want to have all the encrypted user data in one file for convenience, so that users can easily back it up. Also, I don't want (perhaps irrationally) for someone to be able to tell how many photos/folders the user has, even if the actual contents are encrypted.

Comment: It looks like that approach is **not** convenient. But just because you save the on the server in individual files does not need to be apparent to the client.